# Obtaining ID of form in a formset

Tags: django, django-templates

I need a way to set the id of the div that contains each form in a formset to a value that contains a number that is representative of the index of that form.

eg. I want the 2nd form to have a parent div that looks like this

```
<div id="1">  #id could even be "id_form-1-id".
     form
</div>
```

I've found that {{form.id}} produces the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-3-id" id="id_form-3-id">
```

Is there a way that I can extract just the id value (i.e. id_form-3-id) from this string using a template tag?

For reasons that I won't get into, a forloop.counter counter won't reliably return an index as some forms within the formset can be created outside of the typical formset for loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`auto_id`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.auto_id):

```
{{form.id.auto_id}}
```